# Text using custom fontface horribly scrambled on Google chrome - windows 10

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I have a website that uses a custom css fontface for titles. I prepared the font eot/woff/ttf file with fontsquirrel (based on the original ttf file). The fontface rule looks like this, nothing fancy:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bauhaus_heavy_boldregular';
    src: url('font/bauhaus_heavy_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/bauhaus_heavy_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('font/bauhaus_heavy_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('font/bauhaus_heavy_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('font/bauhaus_heavy_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

All my test devices display text using this fontface rule correctly except for one laptop running windows 10 and google chrome. On this device some text (not all!) appears scrambled in a weird way, I get the result you see in the image:

[image: displaying scrambled text]

Does anyone have any idea about what can cause this, and more importantly, how to fix it?

Comment: step 1: given the universal support for WOFF, just use that (with WOFF2 if you really want bleeding edge support), don't try to also load eot/svg/ttf/otf sources, they don't add anything other than support for no-longer-supported browsers. The upside of only having a single font resource is that you've now also ruled out the possibility of "the wrong resource getting used". There is zero guarantee that eot, ttf, and WOFF parsing all do the same thing in IE for instance.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I think. Still would like to know how this is caused though, leaving the question open for now.

Comment: no, absolutely: keep the question open, but remove the other formats anyway: if that solves your problem, you know the solution. If it doesn't, then it wasn't related to multiple formats but now you have much tighter code that other people can critically reason about, instead of having to guess which font is actually getting used first. An related to that, if you have this up and running on the internet, *add the link to that site* so that people can actually look at what's going on. Particularly important in these cases.